# How to execute if else statement stored in a string?

Tags: c#

I have a string like this

**string s = " IF(condition){ return true; } else { return false} ";**

Now I want to execute this string and want result according to the condition like..

If condition is true then return true otherwise false.

Condition would be like (expression == 3) or (expression == "3") or (expression == '3') etc.

And one more thing I am getting this string from html parsing from browser that means i have to execute this like a string i have no other option..

How can i do this in c#

Comment: By creating your own compiler :)

Comment: You need to dynamically compile them first,

Comment: a string should be treated as a string don't go against the norm

Comment: If you can change your language inside string to javascript, then you can use [Javascript.Net](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net)

Comment: What you trying to achieve by doing that? May be there is another way?

Comment: Well, what will be the expected value for `condition`, any samples?

Comment: If all your strings will look like that then you could only focus on `condition` instead of building the whole if statement. `IF(condition){ return true; } else { return false}` is equal to `return condition`

Comment: A bit of useful code or a hint would be highly appreciable ...  @NiyokoYuliawan and everyone .. Thanxx

Comment: Are you getting that string as a return result from any other API call? Or are you coding it by yourself?

Comment: String value is always remain a string.. there no any possible answer to this i guess.